# Application died in status UNMOUNTING: Cannot read property 'injector' of undefined

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angularjs-injector, micro-frontend

I am building microfrontend using Single-Spa-Angular library. I have created three different child app using "ng add single-spa-angular" and two of the app working fine, but one app showing below error:

```
Uncaught app2: Application 'app2' died in status UNMOUNTING: Cannot read property 'injector' of undefined
    at http://<HOSTNAME>:4202/main.js:204363:53
```

and

```
Uncaught app2: Application 'app2' died in status SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js
    at new NgZone (http://<HOST>:4202/main.js:68725:19)
    at getNgZone (http://<HOST>:4202/main.js:69414:13)
    at PlatformRef../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (http://<HOST>:4202/main.js:69312:22)
    at http://<HOST>:4202/main.js:69356:59
```

can any one help me out.

Thanks
Shashi Bhushan Verma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Add the following line in your main.single-spa.ts file:

**import 'zone.js/dist/zone';**

This seemed to work for me.

Comment: Did nothing for me

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively add zone.js in the root-config.js file as script like the following.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zone.js@0.10.3/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
```

As official single-spa documentation says

> The preferred way to ensure only one instance of ZoneJS is loaded on your page is with a script tag in your root-config's HTML file. You should load ZoneJS upfront a single time, before loading SystemJS or any of your microfrontends.

For your reference [docuementation](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/)